# Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?

Tags: java, io, java.util.scanner

I am using the `Scanner` methods `nextInt()` and `nextLine()` for reading input.

It looks like this:

```
System.out.println("Enter numerical value");    
int option;
option = input.nextInt(); // Read numerical value from input
System.out.println("Enter 1st string"); 
String string1 = input.nextLine(); // Read 1st string (this is skipped)
System.out.println("Enter 2nd string");
String string2 = input.nextLine(); // Read 2nd string (this appears right after reading numerical value)
```

The problem is that after entering the numerical value, the first `input.nextLine()` is skipped and the second `input.nextLine()` is executed, so that my output looks like this:

```
Enter numerical value
3   // This is my input
Enter 1st string    // The program is supposed to stop here and wait for my input, but is skipped
Enter 2nd string    // ...and this line is executed and waits for my input
```

I tested my application and it looks like the problem lies in using `input.nextInt()`. If I delete it, then both `string1 = input.nextLine()` and `string2 = input.nextLine()` are executed as I want them to be.

Comment: Or you could be like me and use BufferedReader :) I don't care if it's old school, it has always worked and always will work for me. Also, knowledge of BufferedReader has application elsewhere. I simply don't like Scanner.

Answer (score 1158, accepted):

That's because the [`Scanner.nextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt%28%29) method does not read the *newline* character in your input created by hitting "Enter," and so the call to [`Scanner.nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine%28%29) returns after reading that *newline*.

You will encounter the similar behaviour when you use `Scanner.nextLine` after [`Scanner.next()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next%28%29) or any `Scanner.nextFoo` method (except `nextLine` itself).

**Workaround:**

- Either put a `Scanner.nextLine` call after each `Scanner.nextInt` or `Scanner.nextFoo` to consume rest of that line including *newline*

  ```
  int option = input.nextInt();
  input.nextLine();  // Consume newline left-over
  String str1 = input.nextLine();
  ```
- Or, even better, read the input through `Scanner.nextLine` and convert your input to the proper format you need. For example, you may convert to an integer using [`Integer.parseInt(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) method.

  ```
  int option = 0;
  try {
      option = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
  } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
  }
  String str1 = input.nextLine();
  ```

Comment: Couldn't I use only `option = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());}` instead of full `try{...}`? Is there any weakness of using only above?

Comment: @blekione. You have to use `try-catch`, because `Integer.parseInt` throws `NumberFormatException` when an invalid argument is passed to it. You will learn about exception later on. For E.G: - `Integer.parseInt("abc")`. You don't want "abc" to get converted to int right?

Comment: @blekione. So, in the above case, your code will halt at that point, and you won't be able to continue the execution. With Exception Handling, you can handle such kind of conditions.

Comment: To which extent is the latter better? AFAIK Scanner#nextInt() is way more lenient in finding correct ints, by allowing group commas and locale prefixes and suffixes. Integer#parseInt() allows digits and decimal point only plus an optional sign.

Comment: I personally prefer a [`Scanner#hasNextFoo`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3059367/5394855) check beforehand instead of a try-catch, but that works too.

Comment: Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        Double d = scan.nextDouble();
        int option = 0;
        try {
            option = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            //e.printStackTrace();
        }
        String str = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println("String: " + str);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);

Comment: Use ParseDouble has a new problem, that nextDouble use the regional configuration of decimal (. or ,) but Parsedouble always receive US decimal ( . ).

Comment: Another solution could be to use a delimiter that will also ignore newlines besides just spaces. e.g. `Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in).useDelimiter("\\s+");`

Comment: input.nextLine() not working for me. I am surprised because I have used it before. String s=input().nextLine() works. I don't know why it is demanding a String object.

Comment: A very important issue for new Java programmers and Excellent presentation about the issue.

Comment: If that is the case, Why don't we encounter the same problem if we use `Scanner.next()` call after `Scanner.nextInt()`. Why don't I get a blank string in `Scanner.next()` ?

Comment: thankyou so much for the answer! I am working around my program since an hour but can't figure out the bug. Your first point conveys better than the second according to me @RohitJain

Answer (score 278):

The problem is with the `input.nextInt()` method; it only reads the int value. So when you continue reading with `input.nextLine()` you receive the "\n" Enter key. So to skip this you have to add the `input.nextLine()`.

Try it like this, instead:

```
System.out.print("Insert a number: ");
int number = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // This line you have to add (It consumes the \n character)
System.out.print("Text1: ");
String text1 = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Text2: ");
String text2 = input.nextLine();
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx

Comment: If that is the case, Why don't we encounter the same problem if we use `Scanner.next()` call after `Scanner.nextInt()`. Why don't I get a blank string in `Scanner.next()` ?

Answer (score 99):

It's because when you enter a number then press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, `input.nextInt()` consumes only the number, not the "end of line". When `input.nextLine()` executes, it consumes the "end of line" still in the buffer from the first input.

Instead, use `input.nextLine()` immediately after `input.nextInt()`

Comment: @Victor it's not bug. it's working as specified. you could argue though that there should be an easy way to tell the api to also consume any whitespace following the target input.

Comment: I see. thanks @Bohemian, that exactly what i am arguing. I think that this should be changed, perhaps you can point me where to suggest this "issue" in the next JCP.

Comment: @victor You can request (and find out how to contribute code to) a feature via the [Report a Bug or Request a Feature](http://bugreport.java.com/) page.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx

Comment: If that is the case, Why don't we encounter the same problem if we use `Scanner.next()` call after `Scanner.nextInt()`. Why don't I get a blank string in `Scanner.next()` ?

Answer (score 54):

There seem to be many questions about this issue with `java.util.Scanner`. I think a more readable/idiomatic solution would be to call `scanner.skip("[\r\n]+")` to drop any newline characters after calling `nextInt()`.

EDIT: as @PatrickParker noted below, this will cause an infinite loop if user inputs any whitespace after the number. See their answer for a better pattern to use with skip: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42471816/143585

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx

Comment: I know what we do to remove the data in buffer, but this case, please help me with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33585314/having-issues-with-scanner

Comment: FYI, this will cause an infinite loop is the user types any tabs or spaces after the numeric input. See my answer here for a better skip: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42471816/7098259

Comment: @PatrickParker: it does indeed cause an infinite loop! Thanks, edited the answer to link to yours.

Answer (score 44):

TL;DR
`nextLine()` is safe to call when (a) it is first reading instruction, (b) previous reading instruction was also `nextLine()`.

If you are not sure that either of above is true you can use `scanner.skip("\\R?")` before calling `scanner.nextLine()` since calls like `next()` `nextInt()` will leave potential line separator - created by *return* key which will affect result of `nextLine()`. The `.skip("\\R?")` will let us consume this unnecessary line separator.

`skip` uses regex where

- `\R` represents line separators
- `?` will make `\R` optional - which will prevent `skip` method from:

  - waiting for matching sequence

    - in case of reaching end of still opened source of data like `System.in`, input stream from socket, etc.
  - throwing `java.util.NoSuchElementException` in case of

    - terminated/closed source of data,
    - or when existing data doesn't match what we want to skip

### Things you need to know:

- text which represents few lines also contains non-printable characters between lines (we call them line separators) like
- carriage return (CR - in String literals represented as `"\r"`)
- line feed (LF - in String literals represented as `"\n"`)
- when you are reading data from the console, it allows the user to type his response and when he is done he needs to *somehow* confirm that fact. To do so, the user is required to press "enter"/"return" key on the keyboard.

What is important is that this key beside ensuring placing user data to *standard input* (represented by `System.in` which is read by `Scanner`) also sends OS dependant line separators (like for Windows `\r\n`) after it.

So when you are asking the user for value like `age`, and user types 42 and presses enter, standard input will contain `"42\r\n"`.

### Problem

`Scanner#nextInt` (and other `Scanner#nextType` methods) doesn't allow Scanner to *consume* these line separators. It will read them from `System.in` (how else Scanner would know that there are no more digits from the user which represent `age` value than facing whitespace?) which will remove them from standard input, but **it will also *cache* those line separators internally**. What we need to remember, is that all of the Scanner methods are always scanning starting from the cached text.

Now `Scanner#nextLine()` simply collects and returns all characters *until it finds line separators* (or end of stream). But since line separators after reading the number from the console are found immediately in Scanner's cache, it returns empty String, meaning that Scanner was not able to find any character before those line separators (or end of stream).
BTW `nextLine` also *consumes* those line separators.

### Solution

So when you want to ask for number and then for entire line while avoiding that empty string as result of `nextLine`, either

- consume line separator left by `nextInt` from Scanners cache by
- calling `nextLine`,
- or IMO ***more readable*** way would be by calling `skip("\\R")` or `skip("\r\n|\r|\n")` to let Scanner skip part matched by line separator (more info about `\R`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31060125)
- don't use `nextInt` (nor `next`, or any `nextTYPE` methods) at all. Instead read entire data line-by-line using `nextLine` and parse numbers from each line (assuming one line contains only one number) to proper type like `int` via `Integer.parseInt`.

---

**BTW**: `Scanner#nextType` methods can *skip* delimiters (by default all whitespaces like tabs, line separators) including those cached by scanner, until they will find next non-delimiter value (token). Thanks to that for input like `"42\r\n\r\n321\r\n\r\n\r\nfoobar"` code

```
int num1 = sc.nextInt();
int num2 = sc.nextInt();
String name = sc.next();
```

will be able to properly assign `num1=42` `num2=321` `name=foobar`.

Answer (score 38):

It does that because `input.nextInt();` doesn't capture the newline. you could do like the others proposed by adding an `input.nextLine();` underneath.
Alternatively you can do it C# style and parse a nextLine to an integer like so:

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
```

Doing this works just as well, and it saves you a line of code.

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx

Comment: you have to use try catch here. What will happen if the input is not a number. NumberFormatException need to be handled here.

Comment: This assumes that there is only one int token on each line you try this for.

Comment: If that is the case, Why don't we encounter the same problem if we use `Scanner.next()` call after `Scanner.nextInt()`. Why don't I get a blank string in `Scanner.next()` ?

Comment: @Tushar I wish I remembered, I haven't touched Java since I wrote that answer in '13

Answer (score 19):

Instead of `input.nextLine()` use `input.next()`, that should solve the problem.

Modified code:

```
public static Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.print("Insert a number: ");
    int number = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Text1: ");
    String text1 = input.next();
    System.out.print("Text2: ");
    String text2 = input.next();
}
```

Comment: FYI: merged from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7056749/scanner-issue-when-using-nextline-after-nextxxx

Answer (score 15):

If you want to read both strings and ints, a solution is to use two Scanners:

```
Scanner stringScanner = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner intScanner = new Scanner(System.in);

intScanner.nextInt();
String s = stringScanner.nextLine(); // unaffected by previous nextInt()
System.out.println(s);

intScanner.close();
stringScanner.close();
```

Comment: please do not do this. Just one scanner per inputstream. Also, when you do `intScanner.close();` you close stringScanner + the whole `System.in` for the rest of your execution.

Answer (score 14):

In order to avoid the issue, use `nextLine();` immediately after `nextInt();` as it helps in clearing out the buffer. When you press `ENTER` the `nextInt();` does not capture the new line and hence, skips the `Scanner` code later.

```
Scanner scanner =  new Scanner(System.in);
int option = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); //clearing the buffer
```

Answer (score 14):

If you want to scan input fast without getting confused into Scanner class nextLine() method , Use Custom Input Scanner for it .

### Code :

```
class ScanReader {
/**
* @author Nikunj Khokhar
*/
    private byte[] buf = new byte[4 * 1024];
    private int index;
    private BufferedInputStream in;
    private int total;

    public ScanReader(InputStream inputStream) {
        in = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
    }

    private int scan() throws IOException {
        if (index >= total) {
            index = 0;
            total = in.read(buf);
            if (total <= 0) return -1;
        }
        return buf[index++];
    }
    public char scanChar(){
        int c=scan();
        while (isWhiteSpace(c))c=scan();
        return (char)c;
    }


    public int scanInt() throws IOException {
        int integer = 0;
        int n = scan();
        while (isWhiteSpace(n)) n = scan();
        int neg = 1;
        if (n == '-') {
            neg = -1;
            n = scan();
        }
        while (!isWhiteSpace(n)) {
            if (n >= '0' && n <= '9') {
                integer *= 10;
                integer += n - '0';
                n = scan();
            }
        }
        return neg * integer;
    }

    public String scanString() throws IOException {
        int c = scan();
        while (isWhiteSpace(c)) c = scan();
        StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
        do {
            res.appendCodePoint(c);
            c = scan();
        } while (!isWhiteSpace(c));
        return res.toString();
    }

    private boolean isWhiteSpace(int n) {
        if (n == ' ' || n == '\n' || n == '\r' || n == '\t' || n == -1) return true;
        else return false;
    }

    public long scanLong() throws IOException {
        long integer = 0;
        int n = scan();
        while (isWhiteSpace(n)) n = scan();
        int neg = 1;
        if (n == '-') {
            neg = -1;
            n = scan();
        }
        while (!isWhiteSpace(n)) {
            if (n >= '0' && n <= '9') {
                integer *= 10;
                integer += n - '0';
                n = scan();
            }
        }
        return neg * integer;
    }

    public void scanLong(long[] A) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) A[i] = scanLong();
    }

    public void scanInt(int[] A) throws IOException {
        for (int i = 0; i < A.length; i++) A[i] = scanInt();
    }

    public double scanDouble() throws IOException {
        int c = scan();
        while (isWhiteSpace(c)) c = scan();
        int sgn = 1;
        if (c == '-') {
            sgn = -1;
            c = scan();
        }
        double res = 0;
        while (!isWhiteSpace(c) && c != '.') {
            if (c == 'e' || c == 'E') {
                return res * Math.pow(10, scanInt());
            }
            res *= 10;
            res += c - '0';
            c = scan();
        }
        if (c == '.') {
            c = scan();
            double m = 1;
            while (!isWhiteSpace(c)) {
                if (c == 'e' || c == 'E') {
                    return res * Math.pow(10, scanInt());
                }
                m /= 10;
                res += (c - '0') * m;
                c = scan();
            }
        }
        return res * sgn;
    }

}
```

### Advantages :

- Scans Input faster than BufferReader
- Reduces Time Complexity
- Flushes Buffer for every next input

### Methods :

- scanChar() - scan single character
- scanInt() - scan Integer value
- scanLong() - scan Long value
- scanString() - scan String value
- scanDouble() - scan Double value
- scanInt(int[] array) - scans complete Array(Integer)
- scanLong(long[] array) - scans complete Array(Long)

### Usage :

1. Copy the Given Code below your java code.
2. Initialise Object for Given Class

`ScanReader sc = new ScanReader(System.in);`

3. Import necessary Classes :

`import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;`
 
4. Throw IOException from your main method to handle Exception
5. Use Provided Methods.
6. Enjoy

### Example :

```
import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
class Main{
    public static void main(String... as) throws IOException{
        ScanReader sc = new ScanReader(System.in);
        int a=sc.scanInt();
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
class ScanReader....
```

Answer (score 11):

`sc.nextLine()` is better as compared to parsing the input.
Because performance wise it will be good.

Answer (score 7):

I guess I'm pretty late to the party..

As previously stated, calling `input.nextLine()` after getting your int value will solve your problem. The reason why your code didn't work was because there was nothing else to store from your input (where you inputted the int) into `string1`. I'll just shed a little more light to the entire topic.

Consider *nextLine()* as the odd one out among the *nextFoo()* methods in the Scanner class. Let's take a quick example.. Let's say we have two lines of code like the ones below:

```
int firstNumber = input.nextInt();
int secondNumber = input.nextInt();
```

If we input the value below (as a single line of input)

> 54 234

The value of our `firstNumber` and `secondNumber` variable become 54 and 234 respectively. The reason why this works this way is because a new line feed (*i.e \n*)  ***IS NOT*** automatically generated when the nextInt() method takes in the values. It simply takes the *"next int"* and moves on. This is the same for the rest of the nextFoo() methods except nextLine().

nextLine() generates a new line feed immediately after taking a value; this is what @RohitJain means by saying the new line feed is "consumed".

Lastly, the next() method simply takes the nearest String **without** generating a new line; this makes this the preferential method for taking separate Strings within the same single line.

I hope this helps.. Merry coding!

Comment: what is a "new line feed"?

Comment: @Abcd A new line feed basically means 'starting from a new line'.

Comment: That "54 234" example really clarifies things.

Answer (score 6):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int i = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        double d = scan.nextDouble();
        scan.nextLine();
        String s = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("String: " + s);
        System.out.println("Double: " + d);
        System.out.println("Int: " + i);
    }
```

Comment: If you use the nextLine() method immediately following the nextInt() method, recall that nextInt() reads integer tokens; because of this, the last newline character for that line of integer input is still queued in the input buffer and the next nextLine() will be reading the remainder of the integer line (which is empty).

Answer (score 6):

*if I expect a non-empty input*

avoids:
–  loss of data if the following input is eaten by an unchecked `scan.nextLine()` as workaround
–  loss of data due to only partially read lines because `scan.nextLine()` was replaced by `scan.next()` *(enter: "yippie ya yeah")*
–  `Exception`s that are thrown when parsing input with `Scanner` methods *(read first, parse afterwards)*

```
public static Function<Scanner,String> scanLine = (scan -> {
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    return( s.length() == 0 ? scan.nextLine() : s );
  });
```

used in above example:

```
System.out.println("Enter numerical value");    
int option = input.nextInt(); // read numerical value from input

System.out.println("Enter 1st string"); 
String string1 = scanLine.apply( input ); // read 1st string
System.out.println("Enter 2nd string");
String string2 = scanLine.apply( input ); // read 2nd string
```

Comment: never seen this before. How would this behave in (*beware spam*) the close scenario? https://stackoverflow.com/a/65515359/2148953

Comment: @aran While here the problem is, to prevent an empty input *(working in any scenario)*, is the other problem mentioned above, that the resources of an active `Scanner` are being released through of a wrong placed call of `close`.
The use of [autoclosing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65503259/should-a-scanner-only-be-instantiated-only-once-if-thats-the-case-why-so/66401952#66401952) is the correct way to close the `Scanner` or any other `AutoCloseable`.

Answer (score 6):

In one of my usecase, I had the scenario of reading a **string value preceded by a couple of integer values**. I had to use a "**for / while loop**" to read the values. And none of the above suggestions worked in this case.

Using `input.next()` instead of `input.nextLine()` fixed the issue. Hope this might be helpful for those dealing with similar scenario.

Comment: Short answer is that whitespace matters. If you have multiple integers on the same line, you can still use nextLine and split them, and you still need a nextLine after the last next call on the line of input

Answer (score 5):

**Use 2 scanner objects instead of one**

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter numerical value");    
int option;
Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in);
option = input2.nextInt();
```

Answer (score 5):

As `nextXXX()` methods don't read `newline`, except `nextLine()`. We can skip the `newline` after reading any `non-string` value (`int` in this case) by using `scanner.skip()` as below:

```java
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = sc.nextInt();
sc.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
System.out.println(x);
double y = sc.nextDouble();
sc.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
System.out.println(y);
char z = sc.next().charAt(0);
sc.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
System.out.println(z);
String hello = sc.nextLine();
System.out.println(hello);
float tt = sc.nextFloat();
sc.skip("(\r\n|[\n\r\u2028\u2029\u0085])?");
System.out.println(tt);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code it will fix your problem.

```
System.out.println("Enter numerical value");    
int option;
option = input.nextInt(); // Read numerical value from input
input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter 1st string"); 
String string1 = input.nextLine(); // Read 1st string (this is skipped)
System.out.println("Enter 2nd string");
String string2 = input.nextLine(); // Read 2nd string (this appears right after reading numerical value)
```

Comment: While this solves the problem, it doesn't add any more detail than the original answers or explain why it works

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this problem just make a  **scan.nextLine()**, where **scan** is an instance of the Scanner object. For example, I am using a simple HackerRank Problem for the explanation.

```
package com.company;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class hackerrank {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    double d = scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine(); // This line shall stop the skipping the nextLine() 
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();



    // Write your code here.

    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The `nextLine()` will read enter directly as an empty line without waiting for the text.

Simple solution by adding an extra scanner to consume the empty line:

```java
System.out.println("Enter numerical value");    
int option;
option = input.nextInt(); // Read numerical value from input
input.nextLine();
System.out.println("Enter 1st string"); 
String string1 = input.nextLine(); // Read 1st string (this is skipped)
System.out.println("Enter 2nd string");
String string2 = input.nextLine(); // Read 2nd string (this appears right after reading numerical value)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a very basic problem for beginner coders in java. The same problem I also have faced when I started java (Self Taught).
Actually, when we take an input of integer dataType, it reads only integer value and leaves the newLine(\n) character and this line(i.e. leaved new line by integer dynamic input )creates the problem when we try to take a new input.
eg. Like if we take the integer input and then after try to take an String input.

```
value1=sc.nextInt();
value2=sc.nextLine();
```

the value2 will auto read the newLine character and will not take the user input.

**Solution**:
just we need to add one line of code before taking the next user input i.e.

```
sc.nextLine();
```

or

```
value1=sc.nextInt();
sc.nextLine();
value2=sc.nextLine();
```

Note: don't forget to close the Scanner to prevent memory leak;

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the input.nextInt() method - it only reads the int value. So when you continue reading with input.nextLine() you receive the "\n" Enter key. So to skip this you have to add the input.nextLine(). Hope this should be clear now.

Try it like that:

```
System.out.print("Insert a number: ");
int number = input.nextInt();
input.nextLine(); // This line you have to add (It consumes the \n character)
System.out.print("Text1: ");
String text1 = input.nextLine();
System.out.print("Text2: ");
String text2 = input.nextLine();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    scan.nextLine();//to Ignore the rest of the line after  (integer input)nextInt()
    double d=scan.nextDouble();
    scan.nextLine();
    String s=scan.nextLine();
    scan.close();
    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BufferedReader class to input string, this will not create problems

Answer (score -1):

Why not use a new Scanner for every reading? Like below. With this approach you will not confront your problem.

```
int i = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

Comment: But then you have to close the `Scanner` to prevent memory leak. Wasting time?

Comment: Doesn't the GC take care of that if the Scanner is wrapped in a method? Like: String getInput() {return new Scanner(System.in).nextLine()};

Comment: This is absolutely incorrect.  `nextInt()` won't consume the newline, regardless of whether it's in a "new" `Scanner` or an already used one.